# Close webview xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implement payment method with return URL and using webview open URL with my app. Recent, I'am issue want auto close webview  with response success or fail process payment.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this case. Here is the solution I found.

After creating the WebElement, we bind the Navigating event to a certain method.

```
MyPage.Source = link;
MyPage.Navigating += Webview_Navigating;
```

`MyPage` `WebElment` name.

`link` is my link address

.

Then we perform our transactions here.

```
private void Webview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            var url = e.Url;

            if (url.Contains("status=1"))
            {
                int ordID = 0;
                 
                //save order
            }

        }
```

For me, if the changed link address checkout status=1, the checkout is successful.

You need to call `Url` property in `WebNavigatingEventArgs` to catch the changed url

**If useful, choose.  Good Luck**

Comment: Hi @Emin. Thanks for the solution. But it's not possible for issue. Can me to get response object model to webview with progress payment is success?

Comment: @Jack   You can understand the success of the transaction by looking at the document of the payment system you use. For example, I have: When Succesfully operation, my payment system has changing to `status` 1 by changing the link

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can get response form WebView.
I recommend you use HybridWebView (see: https://github.com/devsmadeofsteel/Plugin.HybridWebView) as alternative.

Examples:

In Xamarin page, create a browser add register a named callback, and add browser to page childs

```
HybridWebViewControl Browser  = new HybridWebViewControl();
//You can load browser content by string or URL, here is string which you can hard code or store in resource files
Browser.ContentType = Plugin.HybridWebView.Shared.Enumerations.WebViewContentType.Internet;
Browser.Source = YourUrl;
Browser.AddLocalCallback(YourCallBackFunctionName, CallBackFunction);
```

When run, ***HybridWebViewControl*** will insert a function with the name you specified in
***YourCallBackFunctionName***, and the single parameter is string type. So, In JavaScript of the page loaded by YourUrl, you can call back with the specified ***CallBackFunctionName***：

```
function AnyFunction() {
    //...

    YourCallBackFunctionName(YourStringParameter);
}
```

When you call ***YourCallBackFunctionName(YourStringParameter)*** in JavaScript, you can get ***YourStringParameter*** in CallBackFunction using C#.
So, you could define different CallBackFunctions or pass different parameters with single CallBackFunction, to control the HybridWebView and the page or view which contain it, such as hide HybridWebView or close the page.

Have a try!